# Why is this variable set to empty string when it is already initialized to an empty string?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have taken the following code snippet from the 5th snippet on this [developer guide on Content Providers.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

The confusion is that in the first statement `String[] mSelectionArgs = {""};`, `mSelectionArgs[0]` IS set to `""`.

Then later if the `mSearchString` is empty (`TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)`), then again `mSelectionArgs[0]` is assigned `""`.

**So the question is that why are they setting it to an empty string when it is already initialized to an empty string?**

```
/*
 * This defines a one-element String array to contain the selection argument.
 */
String[] mSelectionArgs = {""};

// Gets a word from the UI
mSearchString = mSearchWord.getText().toString();

// Remember to insert code here to check for invalid or malicious input.

// If the word is the empty string, gets everything
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)) {
    // Setting the selection clause to null will return all words
    mSelectionClause = null;
    mSelectionArgs[0] = "";

} else {
    // Constructs a selection clause that matches the word that the user entered.
    mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " = ?";

    // Moves the user's input string to the selection arguments.
    mSelectionArgs[0] = mSearchString;

}
...
```

Comment: My guess is that it's just for extra clarity. Like, they're driving home the point that for this example, if the search value is empty, mSelectionArgs[0] is STILL "". But, who knows. It's probably just a style thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for additional clarity and code readability, as noted in another answer, this coding style makes for a less error prone code which is easier to maintain.

This way, if the initial value of `mSelectionArgs` is changed, or new code added which overrides this value before the execution of the `if-else` block, the code of this block will still execute correctly. Without this "rudimentary" assignment, a change as described above could lead to a bug which would be very difficult to trace.

**As a side note:**

This specific code snippet is not that good (yes, I know it is from Android Developers site...) - if you pass `null` as `selection` argument to `query()`, then it is better to also pass `null` as `selectionArgs` argument. I'd modify this sample to something like this (setting both `selection` and `selectionArgs` to null):

```
// Gets a word from the UI

mSearchString = mSearchWord.getText().toString();

// Remember to insert code here to check for invalid or malicious input.

String[] mSelectionArgs = null;

// If the word is the empty string, gets everything
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)) {
    // Setting the selection clause to null will return all words
    mSelectionClause = null;
    mSelectionArgs = null;

} else {
    // Constructs a selection clause that matches the word that the user entered.
    mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " = ?";

    // Moves the user's input string to the selection arguments.
    mSelectionArgs = new String[] {mSearchString};

}
```

**Edit: why the above code snippet is better than the original one?**

It is not an error to pass null as `selection` and non-null as `selectionArgs`. This array will be passed to the specific `ContentProvider` you're addressing, and shouldn't be used at all since `selection` does not contain any `?` placeholders. Any `ContentProvider` violating this assumption is buggy. Although not an error, it just looks weird - why do you pass an object that should be ignored anyway? This also has performance cost (which is higher if `ContentProvider` runs in different process), which is proportional to the size of the object being passed.

**Edit 2: why the above code snippet is MUCH better than the original one?**
Turns out that what I said above might be misleading. I found it out the hard way:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
```

The above exception was thrown because I tried to pass `selectionArgs` which contained more elements than the number of `?` placeholders in `selection`.

These two methods from `SQLiteProgram.java` are to "blame" for this exception:

```
public void bindAllArgsAsStrings(String[] bindArgs) {
    if (bindArgs != null) {
        for (int i = bindArgs.length; i != 0; i--) {
            bindString(i, bindArgs[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}

private void bind(int index, Object value) {
    if (index < 1 || index > mNumParameters) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot bind argument at index "
                + index + " because the index is out of range.  "
                + "The statement has " + mNumParameters + " parameters.");
    }
    mBindArgs[index - 1] = value;
}
```

Now, when I found out about this behavior, I think that the code example from Android Developers site is not just inefficient, but is a total crap!

Bottom line: if you pass `null` as `selection`, pass `null` as `selectionArgs` as well. If `selection` is not null and contains `?` placeholders - make sure that the length of `selectionArgs` array equals the number of `?` placeholders in `selection`.

Comment: "if you pass null as selection argument to query(), then it is better to also pass null as selectionArgs argument." - but why? What happens if `selectionArgs` is an empty string (like in the original snippet)? (Sorry I am a newb)

Comment: @Solace, I added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: in your code you could left `mSelectionArgs` uninitialized.

Comment: @bayou.io, yep, but I always try to be explicit in my code. Even when Lint complaints about unnecessary assignment :)

Comment: @Solace, I found additional reason why the code snippet you've referenced is bad. It is described under "Edit 2" section in the answer. Just in case you're interested...

Answer (score 3):

I like it, because it's symmetric

```
if something
    var = x
else
    var = y
```

It's clear what `var` is under each condition, without needing to go back and visit its initial value.